# Pages update gone wrong

Tags: spotlight, pages

When I spotlight search for Pages on my mac, it opens "pages panel" but not pages. The only way I can find the Pages application is through Launchpad.  Is this something that I can fix in some way?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure Spotlight searches the Applications folder. Go to System Preferences/Spotlight and make sure the Applications folder is checked.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to spring up whenever there is an update with Apple's apps. Not sure why it seems to afflict Apple's apps more than others though.

Try this:

Open the Spotlight system preferences and select the Privacy tab. Drag the Pages.app icon into the window in the preferences. Remove the Pages.app from the list (by selecting the app and clicking the '-' button). You shouldn't have to close and re-open the window.

[image: Spotlight > Privacy]

You should be able to use Spotlight to find it now. Of course, this will also work with Numbers and Keynote when they sneak off.

Answer (score 0):

Why not delete the app and reinstall it from the Mac App Store? That's pretty clean and easy when an update goes sideways. Who knows what else was wrong if the icon is messed up.